# Jquery autocompletebox doesn't always work

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocompletebox

Im having a problem with a jquery autocompletebox in a modal window. Ill try to explain the situation as 
clear as possible. If you have any questions please let me know.

I have a screen with all fields, its a main record. I also have a collection of subrecords in it. I want the user to add information into the subrecords making use of a modal dialog for the child record. One of the fields in the subrecord is the field "Currency". This field should be a autocompletebox. 
The problem is quite simpel but after 2 days i still have no idea how to solve it. The first time the user presses the add button the modal window is opened perfectly. The autocompletebox works also like a charm. But when the user saves the first child and wants to add a second by pressing the add button the modal window opens again. But then i get the error *"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function"* and i cant find out why the first time everything works great but why the second time this error pops up.

The code:

For opening the modal window:

```
<a href="#theModal" class="nav-link btn btn-info float-right" data- 
remote="/Specification/_AddSpecification" data-toggle="modal" data- 
backdrop="static" data-target="#theModal"> Nieuwe specificatie</a>
```

For the autocompletebox (i use a class for this)

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('focus',
                '.CurrencySelect',
                function () {
                    $(this).autocomplete({
                        source: function (request, response) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/Currency/searchCurrencies",
                                type: "POST",
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: { searchValue: request.term },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                                    response($.map(data,
                                        function (item) {
                                            return { label: item.currency.Name, value: item.currency.Id };
                                        }));
                                }
                            });
                        },

                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            //alert(this.id);
                            var idField = this.id.replace('String', '');
                            //alert(idField);
                            $("input[name=" + idField + "]").val(ui.item.value);
                            $("input[name=" + this.id + "]").val(ui.item.label);

                            // retrieve the exchange rate from the selected currency for the specified declarationDate.
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/Currency/getExchangeRate",
                                type: "POST",
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: {
                                    currencyId: ui.item.value,
                                    date: $("#date").val()
                                },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));

                                    // Check if status = success
                                    if (data.status === "success") {

                                        // check if statusmessage = null
                                        if (data.statusmessage == null) {
                                            // Disablen van het veld ExchangeRate.
                                            $("#ExchangeRateReadOnly").attr("disabled", "disabled");

                                            // Vullen van het veld ExchangeRate via een variabele.
                                            var er = data.Value;
                                            $("#ExchangeRateReadOnly").val(er.toString().replace(/\./g, ','));
                                            $("#ExchangeRate").val(er.toString().replace(/\./g, ','));
                                            convertCurrencyToEuro();

                                        } else if (data.statusmessage === "Exchangerate unknown") {
                                            alert(
                                                "Voor de geselecteerde valuta is geen geldige koers bekend. U dient deze zelf op te voeren.");
                                            $('#ExchangeRateReadOnly').prop("disabled", false);
                                            convertCurrencyToEuro();

                                        } else if (data.statusmessage === "No exchangerate needed") {
                                            alert("Er is geen koers nodig voor de geselecteerde valuta.");

                                            $("#ExchangeRateReadOnly").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                                            convertCurrencyToEuro();
                                        } else if (data.statusmessage === "Invalid currency code") {
                                            alert("Er is geen geldige valuta geselecteerd.");
                                            convertCurrencyToEuro();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                });
        });
    </script>
```

I hope that somebody can help me solving this issue.

Please advise,

Kevin

Comment: looks like jquery is not recognized when you load the window again. Did you try debugging this and see whats going ?

Comment: @Nilesh i tried debugging but i can't see anything strange where jquery is not recognized when opening the modal window for the second time. What i did find out it happens only after saving the first child record. if i open the model, fill out all the fields but then press cancel (to discard any changes and close the modal) and reopen the form the autocompletebox still works perfectly fine. After saving the changes and reopen the modal i again get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue. How stupid, jquery was loaded twice. Once in the _layout page and once in the page for parent child records itself. 
After removing it from the parend-child page everything seems to work now like a charm.

Thanks for your help!